# Nextjs global api calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I am developing react based web application using [NEXT.js,](https://github.com/zeit/next.js). As specified in [NEXT.js,](https://github.com/zeit/next.js) documentation to fetch the data before page loads, i am putting required action dispatch code in getInitialProps of the specific page. but some data fetching calls(action dispatch) like fetching authenticated user's data will be common to all the pages, so is there any way to dispatch such actions from single place before page load.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

update, now you can use `getServerSideProps` and `nextjs` provides an easy way to get user cookie : [How to use cookie inside `getServerSideProps` method in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860373/how-to-use-cookie-inside-getserversideprops-method-in-next-js)

--------- old answer ---------

simple answer: use cookie, code refer https://github.com/nextjs-boilerplate/next.js-boilerplate https://github.com/nextjs-boilerplate/next-fetch

-- details --

I had the same question when I first adopt `next.js`, as it worked in react, people prefer use a token to tag authed user and fetch always run in front-end. But as `next.js` made `ssr` a build in feature, I tried and find auth by cookie is possible, and I start https://github.com/nextjs-boilerplate/next.js-boilerplate and split out a fetch based on cookie https://github.com/nextjs-boilerplate/next-fetch

-- how it works --

1.client side fetch:  use fetch option `option.credentials = 'include'` and `option.headers.Cookie=document.cookie` will patch cookie into your request. Bnd when fetch back result, this become wired, you cannot access cookie header, so you have to use another header and additional logic needed in backend logic like `res.header('custom-set-cookie', res.getHeader('set-cookie'))`

2.server side fetch: first you need the express request object, and get cookie like `req.headers.cookie`, then pack it into fetch request option. when fetch back, get cookie like `r.headers._headers[cookieHeaderName]` and pack into response `res.header('set-cookie', setCookie)`

then after you pack this transfer up, you can simply call a json api and cookie will automatically transfered. And if you don't need to change cookie through header (you can through js), you can ommit the extra handle like `res.header('custom-set-cookie', res.getHeader('set-cookie'))` in api

you can try my `ssr login` here http://nextjs.i18ntech.com/login