# How to use cookie inside `getServerSideProps` method in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, cookies, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have to send current language on endpoint. But getting language from Cookie returns undefined inside `getServerSideProps`.

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const lang = await Cookie.get('next-i18next')
    const res = await fetch(`endpoint/${lang}`)
    const data = await res.json()

    return {
        props: { data },
    }
}

export default Index;
```

What is the proper way to get cookie inside `getServerSideProps`?

Answer (score 26):

You can get the cookies from the `req.headers` inside `getServerSideProps`:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const cookies = context.req.headers.cookie;
  return {
    props: {},
  };
}
```

You could then use the [cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) npm package to parse them:

```js
import * as cookie from 'cookie'

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const parsedCookies = cookie.parse(context.req.headers.cookie);
  return { props: {} }
}
```

Answer (score 25):

To avoid having to parse the cookies string from `context.req.headers.cookie`, Next.js also provides the cookies as an object which can be accessed with `context.req.cookies`.

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const lang = context.req.cookies['next-i18next']
    
    // ...
    
}
```

From [`getServerSideProps` documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#provided-req-middleware-in-getserversideprops):

> The `req` in the context passed to `getServerSideProps` provides built in
> middleware that parses the incoming request (`req`). That middleware is:
>
> `req.cookies` - An object containing the cookies sent by the request.
> Defaults to `{}`

Comment: Yap, can be accessed using `context.req.cookies.cookieName` too..

Comment: @FahmiAuliya Of course, I'm only using the `context.req.cookies['next-i18next']` because `next-i18next` has an hyphen and can't be used as `context.req.cookies.next-i18next`, and that's what OP was trying to access.

Comment: i get exceptionally long loading time on the pages where i implement this any idea ?

Comment: @mangrove108 Sorry, where you implement what exactly? This is simply showing how to get cookies from inside `getServerSideProps` - that in itself would not cause long load times. If you have long page load time due to the logic you have inside `getServerSideProps` then that's another issue. Maybe investigate why that code is taking a long time to run, and create a new question for it.

Comment: mmh @juliomalves i m just checking for context.req.cookies and then if its the case do a redirect nothing special i would say

Comment: @mangrove108 From my experience, that wouldn't cause a significant increase in page load times. Feel free to ask a new question with more details about the issue here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I made following change

```
  - const cookies = qs.decode(context.req?.headers?.cookie ?? "");
  // @ts-ignore
  const cookies = context.req?.cookies;```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `parseCookies` function with  [**cookie**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie) package

```
import cookie from "cookie"

function parseCookies(req){
    return cookie.parse(req ? req.headers.cookie || "" : document.cookie);
}
```

And then get access like that.

```
export async function getServerSideProps({ req} ) {
  const cookies = parseCookies(req);

  // And then get element from cookie by name
  
  return { 
     props: {
        jwt: cookies.jwt,
     } 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

how are you doing?
you can use Something like this :

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  console.log(context.req.cookies)
}
```

so easy and so beautifuly!

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Axios this is very simple

- This will work inside `getServerSideProps` method. You can't get access to the cookie by using withCredentials because this is on the server.

```
const { token } = context.req.cookies;
  const response = await axios.get('/staff/single', {
    headers: { Cookie: `token=${token};` },
  });
```

- or try (This will work on the client)

```
  const response = await axios.get('/staff/single', {
    headers: { withCredentials: true },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the cookies from the context.res.getHeader('Set-Cookie') inside getServerSideProps:

```
export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps = async (context) => {
    
      const cookieStore: ReturnType<typeof context.res.getHeader> =
        context.res.getHeader('Set-Cookie');
    
      const cookieStoreParsed: { [key: string]: string } = Array.isArray(
        cookieStore
      )
        ? getValuesFromCookie(cookieStore)
        : {};

// to be get value use cookieStoreParsed[SOME_COOKIE_NAME]
      console.log(cookieStoreParsed[SOME_COOKIE_NAME])
    
      return {
        props: {
          ...something you need
        },
      };
    };
```

Then use the cookie npm package to parse them:

```
import * as cookie from 'cookie'

const getValuesFromCookie = (cookieStore: string[]) =>
      cookieStore.reduce((acc: { [key: string]: string }, cookieElem: string) => {
        const cookieElemParsed = cookie.parse(cookieElem);
        return {
          ...acc,
          ...cookieElemParsed,
        };
      }, {});
```

Answer (score 0):

install '[cookie](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie)' package and use this:

```
export async function getServerSideProps(context){
  const {token} = context.req.cookies
  console.log(token)

  return{
    props:{
    }
  }
}
```