# Next.js getStaticProps localstorage is not defined

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have my user id stored in local storage and I want to access it in the `getStaticProps` to fetch the subscribers of current user but I am getting `Local storage is not defined` error.

Any solutions please?

Here is my code:

```
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const userData = {
    id: localStorage.getItem("user_id"),
  };
  const subscribersAPi = await fetch(
    `url for server`
  );
  const result = await subscribersAPi.json();
  return {
    props: { data: result },
  };
}
```

Comment: [`window.localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) is a Web API only available on the browser. `getStaticProps` runs on the server (and at build-time) in a Node.js environment and has no access to `localStorage`.

Comment: @juliomalves is there any way with which i can pass user id then?

Comment: There isn't any way to pass user-specific data using `getStaticProps`. You could look into using `getServerSideProps` instead and [use cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860373/how-to-use-cookie-inside-getserversideprops-method-in-next-js) to pass the data, rather than using `localStorage`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`localStorage`, `sessionStorage` are among `Window Object` methods  that Browser provides us. [Learn more!](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp)

When server renders the app in SSR, there will be no Browser therefor no `window` exists, thus you cannot access local storage.
Instead you should access them in `window` with an `useEffect`

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    setData(localStorage.getItem("myData"));
  }, []);

  return <div>{data}</div>;
};
```

Comment: But what if i need my userId to fetch data from server? isnt there anyways with which i can pass arguments to my getStaticProps?

Comment: With SSR, yes but it's not recommended. Therefor SSR isn't useful for apps where we have dynamic routes. You can use `getStaticPaths` it works like getStaticProps but request are limited since with each build it calls the API, and API limits continuous requests

Comment: Here is documentation for `getStaticProps` https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching#getstaticpaths-static-generation