# Getting cookie client side Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

Im trying to get cookies on client side `getCookie` from `cookies-next`, and im facing issue that on initial render next.js is crashing with error `Cannot read properties of undefined` , but in console cookie has some value always.

When im trying to pass cookie from server using `getServerSideProps`, i get error from `eslint` `Async arrow function 'getServerSideProps' has no 'await' expression.` and when i remove `async` i get `ts` error `getServerSideProps should return promise<...>` etc

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]?

Answer (score 0):

I think this question is the same as yours: [How to use cookie inside `getServerSideProps` method in Next.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63860373/how-to-use-cookie-inside-getserversideprops-method-in-next-js)

ESLint is saying that you are unnecessarily marking `getServerSideProps` as async in a function that does not use `await`, however that syntax is required in Next.js so you can disable that rule.

Comment: when i remove `async` from `getServerSideProps` it shows `ts` error that `getServerSideProps should return Promise<....>` and etc

Comment: You're right, I think it might be a problem with ESLint. If you're using TS try adding the `GetServerSideProps` as seen [here](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/get-server-side-props#getserversideprops-with-typescript), or just disable the ESLint rule entirely. Let me know what works and I will update my answer.

Comment: Probably easiest way will be just to disable ESlint rule